# DLLImport issues when changing target Dot net framework from 4.5 to 2.0

Tags: c#, dllimport

I want to compile my program to run on XP and dot net 2.0.
I changed the target framework from 4.5 to 2.0 and removed "using System.Linq" and "using System.Threading.Tasks" from all files.

Now the DLLImport doesn't load and the program crashes when it get to the call.
The error is "System.BadImageFormatException"

Prior to the framework downgrade the program worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make all the DLL's are running the 2.0 framework. Sounds like you're off somewhere.

Comment: Check to make sure that your .NET app and the DLL you are `DLLImport` 'ing are still all 32 or 64-bit.  Don't mix them up

Comment: The DLL is compiled and I have no control other than loading it in the code. How do I make it runs as a DLL on 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the platform of your native dll (x86 or x64). You can do that with the DUMPBIN utility:

```
dumpbin /headers yournative.dll
```

Check the **machine** header (x86 or x64)

Then you must compile to x86 or x64 your VS project (you can not use AnyCPU).

You can check the platform of your managed assembly with the CORFLAGS utility:

```
corflags yourmanaged.exe
```

Check the **PE** and the **32BIT** headers (PE32 & 0: Any CPU, PE32 & 1: x86, PE32+ & 0: x64)

The two platforms must match.

Comment: You are missing the most likely reason why that DLL cannot run on XP.  Also visible with dumpbin /headers, sub-system field.  Likely to be set to 6.00 these days, XP is 5.02

Comment: Yes a native dll produced by VS 2012/2013/2015 will have a 6.00 subsystem version (not compatible with XP) whereas a dll produced by VS 2010 will have a 5.02 subsystem version. If it is your case, you can try to edit the subsystem with editbin like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362109/200443